# Perform action on field deletion (trigger on metadata)

Tags: apex, trigger, metadata

For the purpose of an app I need to be able to perform some actions, either via apex code or workflow/process builder to update another object, however I can't seem to find a documented way to do it. Is it possible on the platform

e.g

If TestField__c on Account is deleted (or the type is changed) the object Object_Status__c needs to be notified and register it. So I need the api name of the field and the action that was taken on it.

Comment: I believe there are 2 options here -- query SetupAuditTrail using SOAP API and see what was deleted/changed etc in scheduled job OR use schedule job, get describe on object, compare with previous state. Both will not be immediate, but with some delay

Comment: I thought about that but the problem I have with this is that the job should be launched as soon as the metadata of the object is changed. But it's already a start.

Comment: I isn't currently possible with a direct trigger. Had a discussion about this on twitter for detecting metadata changes in general - https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/943920383043837952

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently a native way to detect and take actions immediately after a change to the Metadata occurs.

As kurunve commented, there is the [SetupAuditTrail](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_setupaudittrail.htm) in the SOAP API.

> Represents changes you or other admins made in your org’s Setup area for at least the last 180 days.

You would need to poll this on an interval to detect the change.

Likewise, you could also directly poll and compare metadata to detect changes such as a field added or deleted.

---

There was a discussion along similar lines on [twitter recently](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey/status/943920383043837952) about having an automation point to detect metadata changes. My position was that a trigger isn't really the right place for such automation. A trigger that is itself described in metadata doesn't seem like a great place to monitor metadata changes.

Platform events however would be useful for this as they would execute outside the actual deployment.

Comment: Is solution available now?